# Automation of IIS Farms

Tags: powershell, iis

I am trying to automate many different aspect of IIS when site are running using the server farm option. My problem is I am unable to figure out which command if any can get any values from the server farm themselves. All I am currently able to get is information's on the basic IIS settings or anything related to a website (except farm).

This is all the `Get` method I have and none seems to have an option for server farms. Am I missing a component on my server ?

```
Cmdlet          Get-IISAppPool                                     1.0.0.0    IISAdministration
Cmdlet          Get-IISCentralCertProvider                         1.0.0.0    IISAdministration
Cmdlet          Get-IISConfigAttributeValue                        1.0.0.0    IISAdministration
Cmdlet          Get-IISConfigCollection                            1.0.0.0    IISAdministration
Cmdlet          Get-IISConfigCollectionElement                     1.0.0.0    IISAdministration
Cmdlet          Get-IISConfigElement                               1.0.0.0    IISAdministration
Cmdlet          Get-IISConfigSection                               1.0.0.0    IISAdministration
Cmdlet          Get-IISServerManager                               1.0.0.0    IISAdministration
Cmdlet          Get-IISSharedConfig                                1.0.0.0    IISAdministration
Cmdlet          Get-IISSite                                        1.0.0.0    IISAdministration
```

The minimum I would need to get is the health check status of each server in each farms. All my server in all my farms implement the health check status to know if they are online or not. If I can at least get that value I can manage the rest from the config files on all the servers. Obviously I rather be able to get every value from a PowerShell command.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Web Farm Framework cmdlets for Windows PowerShell to configure and manage your server farm. You must have Windows PowerShell installed on the web farm controller. For more information about "Web Farm Framework 2.0 for IIS 7 cmdlets for Windows PowerShell", you can refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/web-hosting/microsoft-web-farm-framework-20-for-iis-7/web-farm-framework-20-for-iis-cmdlets-for-windows-powershell).

Comment: Unfortunately this is only for SharePoint server.

Comment: Unfortunately not. It not finding the module and when i search for the error all solution is to reinstall SharePoint server. I found an install for Web Farm 3.0 on microsoft website but the link to download is dead so I assume they do not support it anymore.